# ts a type that is a function and a property at the same time

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am reading ts handbook and I found something really confusing I am not sure how to use it. Basically is a param that is a function and a property at the same time.

```
// the definition
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
// the function that acceps the params
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}

// but how can I use it?
// case 1 fail

doSomething({ description: 'xxx'})

/* Argument of type '{ description: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DescribableFunction'.
  Type '{ description: string; }' provides no match for the signature '(someArg: number): boolean'.(2345)
*/


//case 2 fail

doSomething((x) => x > 0})

/*
Argument of type '(x: number) => boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DescribableFunction'.
  Property 'description' is missing in type '(x: number) => boolean' but required in type 'DescribableFunction'.(2345)
input.tsx(2, 3): 'description' is declared here.
*/
```

document
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures

example
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtioBeKAbwCgooATBFVMcqgLinjA0xAOYBuZlAAU8CgFsIAQWQj+xQnPQRkASn7oKFPJmISAvhIBmJMpWqsKAZXkRgAC1Sipl4vzhI0LFwCGx5iHQZJRCpZPAA6HAoRb2I49gCuMKgAaigAIihkV0JkYghWfJyoHykANh0dc0ZGB2cFd09k+jYONG47fgByAA9RwbMdFqcXDq8pYYiaAD4oYagVgAYJoA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```js
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
```

means that there is some function `(someArg: number): boolean` with static property `description`.

Just like any function has static property `name` or static methods `call`,`apply`,`bind` ...

```js
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}

const fn: DescribableFunction = (someArg: number) => true
fn.description = 'hello';

doSomething(fn) // ok
```

Comment: How is that function? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

the main point is :
1.first to declare Your function ,like:
const fn: DescribableFunction = (someArg: number) => true

2.then to add value for property "description",like:
fn.description = 'hello';
If You do 2. before 1.,wouldn't work.